# How to export gt table as rtf from Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, rtf, gt

I need to generate an HTML document which displays a gt table. At the same time, it should export the table as a rtf file. I have the following process, but when I knit the document I get an unexpected output in the rtf file which is different from when I run the code interactively.

````
---
title: "rtf test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results='asis'}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

out <- mtcars %>% 
  head() %>% 
  gt()

print(out)

gtsave(out, filename = "rtf_test.rtf")
```
````

The rtf output look like the following:

```
!!!!!RAW-KNITR-CONTENT{\rtf\ansi\ansicpg1252{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset0\fprq0 Calibri;}{\f1\froman\fcharset0\fprq0 Courier;}}{\colortbl;\red211\green211\blue211;}

\trowd\trrh0\trhdr

\pard\plain\uc0\qr\clvertalc\clpadb50\clpadfb3\clpadr50\clpadfr3\clpadl50\clpadfl3\clpadt50\clpadft3\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw40\brdrcf1\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw40\brdrcf1\clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf1\clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf1\cellx861
\intbl {\f0 {\f0\fs20 mpg}}\cell
\pard\plain
...
```

Instead of the desired table in the rtf file which I get when I run the code interactively:
[image: mtcars_table_head]

I have tried using writeLines instead of gtsave and removing results = 'asis' from the code chunk but nothing I do seems to export the table as I want it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like this is a known, reported issue: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/674

Comment: The solution in the issue works perfectly! Thank for pointing me in the right direction @MrFlick.